# ¿Cómo puedo mostrar el resultado de un Grep cuando otro resultado de Grep dé un valor determinado?

Tags: linux, unix, shell-script, grep

Necesito hacer dos busquedas en el mismo archivo con cadenas diferentes, es decir, tengo archivos de log donde puedo ver, cuando mis programas fallan, "Job Failed" así:

```
grep -l 'Job Failed' /logs/programas/*
```

El problema es que ahora también necesito que de los que fallan, me diga el nombre, que está en otra linea diferente a la del Job Failed por lo que no puedo hacer lo siguiente:

```
grep -Pl 'Job Failed|nombre' /logs/programas/*
```

Y no consigo unir esos dos grep con un pipe en algo que me dé lo que quiero precisamente porque el grep solo me saca una linea o la otra.

¿Como podría realizar esa doble búsqueda? ¿Sería un script a parte?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para esto puedes utilizar [xargs](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html). Le pasas un comando con unos argumentos iniciales, y lee del *standard input* una lista de ítems para ejecutar el comando una vez con cada ítem:

```sh
grep -l 'Job Failed' /logs/programas/* | xargs grep 'name'
```

Por ejemplo si el primer `grep` te da esto:

```
/logs/programas/a1.prog
/logs/programas/a8.prog
```

lo que ejecutará el comando de arriba es:

```
grep 'name' /logs/programas/a1.prog
grep 'name' /logs/programas/a8.prog
```

Como los nombres de ficheros pueden contener espacios y saltos de línea, es conveniente utilizar la opción `-0` de xargs y decirle al `grep` que delimite los resultados con NULLs (usando la opción `-Z` o `--null`):

```sh
grep -lZ 'Job Failed' /logs/programas/* | xargs -0 grep 'name'
```

Comment: Perfecto era esto lo que necesitaba. Me encanta poder darte el tick de resuelto. Muchas gracias.