# ¿Cómo excluyo líneas específicas de un resultado de un Grep?

Tags: linux, unix, shell-script, grep

Estoy intentando realizar una búsqueda doble con un grep, usando `xargs` para obtener los programas que me han fallado en un mes concreto.
Los fallos los puedo identificar con un parámetro que aparece como RC=(aquí vendría un número, por ejemplo RC=255) además de que en el log también aparece la cadena "Job Failed" en otra línea diferente.

Entonces buscaría así:

```
grep -lZ 'Job failed' /logs/programas/*202006* | xargs grep 'RC=200' | wc -l
```

Y esto me devolvería el número concreto (por ejemplo 400), de los que hay con ese tipo de RC, por lo que está bien, pero cuando intento sacar los que NO son RC=200 (para separar los tipos 200 de cualquier otro fallo con la opcion `-v` para omitir y `-l` para listar) pasa a devolverme todos los logs y no la diferencia entre todos los fallos menos los fallos tipo 200 (P.e. Si hubiera 1000 logs deberia sacar 1000-400=600) sin embargo obtengo 1000 igualmente:

```
grep -lZ 'Job failed' /logs/programas/*202006* | xargs grep -lv 'RC=200' | wc -l
```

Entiendo que este `grep` está mal pero no sé ni porqué ni como arreglarlo.

Ejemplo de log que entra:

```
Begin time Thu Jun 18 08:00:53 CEST 2020
 [ EXEC ] Unblocking DDs ...
 End step [CONDITION] with RC=200 at Thu Jun 18 08:00:53 CEST 2020

   Start time:  Thu Jun 18 08:00:33 CEST 2020
   End time:  Thu Jun 18 08:00:53 CEST 2020

Job failed.
```

¿Podríais ayudarme a saber qué estoy haciendo mal?

Muchas gracias por adelantado.

Comment: Hola, Sergio. ¿Podrías, por favor, editar la pregunta y colocar un texto de ejemplo de lo que intentas extraer con grep? Una cosa, no necesitas xargs para volver a hacer un grep. Aunque la definición de xargs es ```build and execute command lines from standard input``` no hace falta para cada vez que hagas un grep.

Comment: Entiendo que todo esto viene de tu anterior pregunta [¿Cómo puedo mostrar el resultado de un Grep cuando otro resultado de Grep dé un valor determinado?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/370477/83). Coincido con @Adrian en que un ejemplo básico sería de mucha ayuda, igual que en la pregunta anterior

Comment: por ejemplo, sería interesante saber si un mismo fichero puede tener RC=200 y RC!=200 a la vez. O si "Job failed" ocurre por igual en ficheros de un tipo y otro. En definitiva, un [mcve]

Comment: Hola, acabo de editar la pregunta por un ejemplo, solo hay un RC por log. Como podéis ver en la linea 3 esta el RC y en la 8 el job failed. Si necesitáis alguna otra manera de hacerlo podéis decirme sin problemas. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dado que cada fichero tiene solamente un bloque de "Job failed" con su texto correspondiente de "RC=xxx", creo que lo suyo es buscar todos los `RC=xxx` y luego quitar los que son `RC=200`:

```
grep -lZ 'Job failed' * | xargs grep -E 'RC=\d+' | grep -v 'RC=200'
#                               \______________/   \______________/
#                                     |            excluye los RC=200
#                                     |
#                         selecciona todos los RC=número
```

De este modo el primer `grep` cogerá ya solamente las líneas importantes y con el segundo excluirás las que no te interesan.

---

Lo que te estaba pasando es que al hacer `xargs grep -lv 'RC=200'` por allí se te colaban todas las líneas que no fueran `RC=200` como por ejemplo "Star time" y todas esas.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda fedorqui, pero en este caso no me devuelve nada el grep. Deberia obtener resultados porque sé que hay errores que no son del tipo 200 entre los que estoy buscando. ¿Podría faltar algun trozo de codigo? muchas gracias en serio

Comment: @SergioChuky nótese que el primer grep no tiene los ficheros que tú decías, sería `grep -lZ 'Job failed' /logs/programas/*202006*` en lugar del `grep -lZ 'Job failed' *` que yo puse. Una vez asegurado que tienes esa parte bien, ¿te devuelve algo cuando le haces el pipe a `xargs grep -E 'RC=\d+'`?

Comment: Si si, la ruta de busqueda del grep estaba puesta, pero ahora he omitido la parte | grep -v 'RC=200' y no obtengo nada. Estoy ejecutando: grep -lZ 'Job failed' /logs/programas/*202006* | xargs grep -E 'RC=\d+'

Comment: @SergioChuky lo mismo es por la versión de Grep que usas, que no reconoce `\d+` para indicar dígitos. Prueba a ver con `xargs grep -E 'RC=[0-9]+'`. Básicamente, busco cadenas del tipo "RC=número".

Comment: Más razón que un Santo tienes. Ahora si funciona. Sólo por curiosidad, si hubiera mas de un RC por fichero, ¿como se procedería?

Comment: @SergioChuky qué bien! Depende de lo que quieras contar. Si quieres ver cuántos bloques hay de cada, el comando que puse en mi respuesta ya valdría. Si quisieras ver cuántos ficheros son íntegramente de un tipo u otro, habría que pensar opciones, seguramente ya usando Awk para ello.